# Renaming the column headers from an iterative list of ranges using Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

```
opvalue_time.columns = opvalue_time.rename(lambda x: "Vol_" + x for x in range(4,80,1))
```

i already have a dataset with 80 columns , need to update the column headers as Vol_4, ....Vol_80.
Currently the columns are 0(no headers)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the `rename` method can directly process a generator expression. Instead, you can use a dictionary comprehension to create a mapping of old column names to new ones, or directly assign a new list of column names to `opvalue_time.columns`. You could try this instead:

```
opvalue_time.columns = ["Vol_" + str(x) for x in range(4, 80)]
```

This assumes your DataFrame initially has 76 columns, matching the range specified (you may need to adjust the range as necessary)

Comment: Great , it works like a charm. Thanks a lot Robert Long

Comment: Currently the range is an integer, since range() function doesnt accept float datatypes. What could be done if the range is Float and not integer e.g 0.5...0.80

Comment: You're very wellcome. The problem with `range`, in this instance, as you correctly note, is that it only works with integers. So we can use a different function. `numpy.arange` which supports floats, hopefully will do the trick. This allows for the generation of floating-point numbers within a specified range. So, let's try this: `opvalue_time.columns = ["Vol_" + format(x, '.2f') for x in np.arange(0.5, 0.81, 0.01)]`

Comment: Thanks once again Robert. I am new to python coding , therefore where can i get any referencce material which can provide more understanding about the rules of Python methods or classes. eg this statement from above  "I don't think the rename method can directly process a generator expression"? where can i get more understanding about these rules?.

Comment: Again you are very welcome. Honestly, my advice is to just do as much python programming as possible. What programming background do you have ? Make some simple applications as side-projects Pay strict attention to the output in your terminal (I assume you use an IDE such as VScode ?) as these errors and warnings are important. Follow some online tutorials. Sadly this website is not for discussions like this.. There are chat rooms but they don't work well for me. I don't mind if you connect with me on LinkedIn (link is on my SO profile) and we can have a little chat on there.

Comment: Also, I would appreciate it if you can give my answer an upvote, and if it's solved the problem, please "accept" it by clicking on the tick mark :)